# How Can You Animate Growing Vines to Wrap Around Objects In a Video?

Tags: animation, mesh, video-sequence-editor, movie-clip-editor

I am making a film where the main character can use plant manipulation. For a scene, I wanted to make an effect where vines could grow from her arms and wrap around objects in the video. I know how to make growing vines, but I can't figure out how to make it wrap around the objects in the video clip. Is there any way I could do that?

Comment: Oh man! That sounds super awesome!

Comment: So you can grow and control the vines to grow around a 3d object? but you want to make it appear as though it goes around something in a video, so you can add it to the video. I think you are looking for [motion tracking](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/movie_clip_editor/tracking/introduction.html) so you can get a 3d object to move in sync with a video object.

Comment: I don't know, how your vines are created, but the cast modifier might work

Comment: @sambler Yeah, that's what I meant to say. I wanted to give the illusion that the vine was wrapping around one of the actor's legs.

Comment: @aky-her I created them by creating a curve with a NURBS Path and beveling it with a Bezier Circle. Then, I resized them and turned the map taper on. And I'll try that! Thank you!